# some problems about replacing imagebutton‘s background

Tags: android, selector, imagebutton

I use “selector” to replace imagebutton's background.Now the background can be replace only when I press the imagebutton.If I don't press it, the background will become original picture.I want to have this result: The original background is No.1 picture.After I press it,it will be replaced by No.2 picture even if I don't press it.
[image]

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/nav_product"></item>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/nav_product_a"></item>
```

In the selector,it has many parameters.I don't know I should use which one.Or must I code in Activity?

Comment: Please add the result you get & the expected result images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following .xml file for your problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_btnopen_hover">
    </item>
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_btnopen_hover">
    </item>
    <item 
        android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_btnopen_hover">
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_btnopen">
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/nav_product"></item>
```

And play around with the other states:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList